# Tengo un app rss que abre el url en un webView al principio cargaba muy bien luego se empezó a cerrar

Tags: android-studio

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView1.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
        webView1 = findViewById(R.id.webvi);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        webView1.loadUrl(bundle.getString("url"));

    }
```

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: com.example.ariel.rss, PID: 10355
>                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.ariel.rss/com.example.ariel.rss.WebView}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.webkit.WebSettings android.webkit.WebView.getSettings()' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
>                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.webkit.WebSettings
>   android.webkit.WebView.getSettings()' on a null object reference
>                                                                              at com.example.ariel.rss.WebView.onCreate(WebView.java:13)
>                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te fijas estas utilizando los métodos del `WebView` antes de instanciarlo. Ese es el origen del error, ya que utilizas los métodos del `WebView` antes de crearlo. E incluso, no solo los estas utilizando antes de instanciar el `WebView` si no antes de inflar el layout de la actividad. Los métodos `super()` y `setContentView()` deben ser los primeros dos métodos del `onCreate()`.

Para corregir el problema, instancia el `WebView` antes de utilizar sus métodos. De la siguiente manera:

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view); // Inflas el layout de la actividad

    webView1 = findViewById(R.id.webvi); // Instancias el WebView

    webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    webView1.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);   

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    webView1.loadUrl(bundle.getString("url"));
}
```